# Variable no almacena el valor asignado en una función para introducir y validar enteros

Tags: python, validación, python-2.x, números-enteros

Estoy haciendo un programa para calcular notas de una clase. Para asegurarme de que en el como número de alumnos se introduce un entero, he hecho esta función:

```
def lee_entero(valor):
    while True:
        valor = raw_input("Ingrese el numero de alumnos: ")
        try:
            valor = int(valor)
            return valor
        except ValueError:
            print "ATENCION: Debe ingresar un numero entero."
```

Sin embargo, la función me devuelve siempre 0 y no el número que haya introducido por teclado. ¿Por qué sucede esto?

Comment: Buenas, ¿Está correctamente tabulado el código? en el ejemplo que has puesto parece que el `while` está a la misma altura que el `def`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En Python no se pasan argumentos ni por valor ni por referencia, los **argumentos son pasados realmente por asignación**, teniendo en cuenta que la asignación solo crea una referencia al objeto. Es decir, cuando pasamos  un objeto (`foo("Hola mundo")`) a una función lo que realmente hacemos es asignarle a dicho parámetro la referencia al objeto, si le pasamos una variable (`s = "Hola Mundo"`; `foo(s)`) le asignamos al argumento la referencia  a la que apunta la variable en ese momento.

El problema es que `int` es un objeto inmutable, por lo que cualquier supuesta "modificación" de la variable implica la creación de un nuevo objeto y una reasignación  a dicha variable de la referencia de este nuevo objeto.

Imaginemos que tenemos este código:

```
n = 0
lee_entero(n)
```

recordemos que las variables en Python no son más que identificadores asociados a la referencia de un objeto en memoria, cuando hacemos `lee_entero(n)` le asignamos al argumento `valor` la referencia al objeto a la que apunta la variable `n`, hay que tener en cuenta que `valor` y `n` no son alias, son dos nombres eventualemente asociados a la misma referencia.  Cuando hacemos `valor = int(valor)` creamos un nuevo objeto `int` y asignamos su referencia a la variable `valor`, de forma que ahora `n` y `valor` apuntan a objetos distintos.

La opción mas simple es que uses el retorno de la función directamente:

```
def lee_entero():
    while True:
        valor = raw_input("Ingrese el numero de alumnos: ")
        try:
            valor = int(valor)
        except ValueError:
            print "ATENCION: Debe ingresar un numero entero."
        else:
            return valor

num_alumnos =  lee_entero()
```

Podemos verlo más claro simplificando el ejemplo:

```
def foo(valor):
    print("Id del objeto al que apunta el argumento 'valor':", id(valor))
    valor += 5  # Intento de modificar in-place valor
    print("Id del objeto al que apunta el argumento 'valor' tras reasignar:", id(valor))

n = 0
print("Id del objeto al que apunta la variable global 'n':", id(n))
num_alumnos = foo(n)
print(n)
```

Lo cual nos da una salida algo así:

> Id del objeto al que apunta la variable global 'n': 139721658083456
>   Id del objeto al que apunta el argumento 'valor': 139721658083456
>   Id del objeto al que apunta el argumento 'valor' tras reasignar: **139721658083616**
>   0

Como se puede ver `valor` deja de apuntar al mismo objeto en memoria en el momento que intentamos modificarlo.

> **Nota:** Como norma general por convención y legibilidad, cuando una función modifica in-place una variable pasada como argumento la función retorna `None`. No es buena practica intentar modificar la variable in-place y al mismo tiempo retornarla.

Comment: Justo hace un momento me he dado cuenta de ese fallo, ahora acabo de confirmar el error. Muchas gracias!